# Fade out sankey links if they are not connected to a node onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'd like to be able to fade out all of the links that are not connected to a particular node in a sankey diagram when that node is clicked.

```
       var link = svg.append("g").selectAll(".link")
           .data(energy.links)
           .enter().append("path")
           .attr("class", "link")
           .attr("d", path)
           .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return 16; })
           .style("stroke", function(d){return d.color;})
           .sort(function(a, b) { return b.dy - a.dy; });
```

The result should be that all unconnected links fade when a node is clicked.

I am not able to think of the logic required to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Link objects have a source and target node object. If you selectAll links and style their opacity based on if the id you are using nodes matches the clicked node. For example if 'name' is the unique ID, then

```
node.on("click", function(d) {
   link.style("opacity", function(l) {
      if (l.source.name == d.name || l.target.name == d.name) {
         return 1
      } else {
         return 0.1
      }
   })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution Tom. It worked perfectly and gave me some insight into some other things I'd like to do with my sankey diagram.